# unix timestamp to hours ago

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nsdate

I have the following code:

```
 NSDate *commentPostedDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[self.newsFeedStream_.timestamp_ intValue]];
    NSLog(@"TIMESTAMP IS %@", self.newsFeedStream_.timestamp_);

    int interval = (int) [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:commentPostedDate] / 60;
    [commentPostedDate release];

    NSString *timePosted = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d hours ago", interval];
```

However this doesn't seem to return the correct hours ago. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNIX timestamps are usually in seconds, so why are you dividing by 60 if you want hours?

There are 3600 seconds in an hour, not 60.

Answer (score 0):

`NSTimeInterval` is a `double` value containing the number of seconds. In particular, you should divide by the number of seconds in an hour which is `60*60`:

```
int interval = (int) ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:commentPostedDate] / 3600);
```